# Toolbar Widget Support Library

Tags: android, mobile

I am bit of confusion, I update my SDK and eclipse tool for android application development. But in sdk->extras->android->support->v7 folder I not found toolbar widget.

Comment: support->v7->appcompact  has toolbar

Comment: Thanks bill gates for the suggestion